# javascript: getting the name of the calling function

Tags: javascript

I'm writing an error event handler that captures an error and make an ajax call to the server to report it. The problem is that a lot of times, my code looks like this:

```
function A() {

  //lots of works to calculate SomeParameters; can bug
  CalledVeryOften(SomeParameters);
}

function CalledVeryOften(SomeParameters) {
  // a little bit of work
}
```

If I capture the event in function A (or B, C, D...), great! But the problem is that if the window.onerror event fires in CalledVeryOften then it might be that the parameters might not be properly calculated.

Is there a way in CalledVeryOften to determine which function it was called from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the calling function can be obtained via the deprecated `arguments.callee.caller.name` property <sup>MDN: [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee)</sup>.

Another method is by parsing the value of [`new Error().stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack).

In Chrome you can use:

```
var stackTrace = {};
Error.captureStackTrace(stackTrace); // Get the stack trace
stackTrace = stackTrace.stack;       // Formatted string
```